# replace values in non standard Json files in pyspark

Tags: json, pyspark, databricks

I need help to solve an issue in Databricks preferably with pyspark code.

I have a troublesome json format, that creates issues when importing the file. The issues lie in the data element, that has been enumerated with 58251 and 58252. The desired state would be to remove this key/numerator. The same issue goes for the "lines" elements 40000, 40001 etc that also would be better with a blank. See example code/json below.

```html
jsonfile= """[ {
      "success":true,
      "numRows":2,
      "data":{
         "58251":{
            "invoiceno":"58251",
            "name":"invoice1",
            "companyId":"1000",
            "departmentId":"1",
            "lines":{
               "40000":{
                  "invoiceline":"40000",
                  "productid":"1",
                  "amount":"10000",
                  "quantity":"7"
               },
               "40001":{
                  "invoiceline":"40001",
                  "productid":"2",
                  "amount":"9000",
                  "quantity":"7"
               }
            }
         },
         "58252":{
            "invoiceno":"58252",
            "name":"invoice34",
            "companyId":"1001",
            "departmentId":"2",
            "lines":{
               "40002":{
                  "invoiceline":"40002",
                  "productid":"3",
                  "amount":"7000",
                  "quantity":"6"
               },
               "40003":{
                  "invoiceline":"40003",
                  "productid":"2",
                  "amount":"9000",
                  "quantity":"7"
               },
"40004":{
                  "invoiceline":"40004",
                  "productid":"2",
                  "amount":"9000",
                  "quantity":"7"
               }            }         }      }   }]"""
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json(jsonfile)
display(df)
```

Is it possible to change the json file to the format below with pyspark code?

The desired json format below:

```html
jsonfile= """[ {
  "success":true,
  "numRows":2,
  "data":[
     {
        "invoiceno":"58251",
        "name":"invoice1",
        "companyId":"1000",
        "departmentId":"1",
        "lines":[
           {
              "invoiceline":"40000",
              "productid":"1",
              "amount":"10000",
              "quantity":"7"
           },
           {
              "invoiceline":"40001",
              "productid":"2",
              "amount":"9000",
              "quantity":"7"
           }
        ]
     },
     {
        "invoiceno":"58252",
        "name":"invoice34",
        "companyId":"1001",
        "departmentId":"2",
        "lines":[
           {
              "invoiceline":"40002",
              "productid":"3",
              "amount":"7000",
              "quantity":"6"
           },
           {
              "invoiceline":"40003",
              "productid":"2",
              "amount":"9000",
              "quantity":"7"
           },
           {
              "invoiceline":"40004",
              "productid":"2",
              "amount":"9000",
              "quantity":"7"
           }            
           ]        
           }      ]   }]"""
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json(jsonfile)
display(df)
```

Comment: Your expected JSON format is invalid. You cannot have value without a key. You probably want "data" is an array instead?

Comment: you are correct. And the correct term is an array.

I see that the json nested arrays should be surrounded by "[" and "]". I have corrected this in the required json. But converting format

"data":{
         "58251":{

to:

"data":[{

maybe very difficult to handle in code? The source json file would contain thousands of these objects, and in two different nested levels.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an interesting problem. The main idea of my solution is looping through your schema to build the map between the company's ID and its lines, then select and reconstruct another JSON from there.

###### Build mapping

```py
# my `a.json` file has exact content as your sample json
df = spark.read.json('a.json', multiLine=True)

mapping = {d.name: d.dataType[3].dataType.fieldNames() for d in df.schema['data'].dataType.fields}
# {'58251': ['40000', '40001'], '58252': ['40002', '40003', '40004']}
```

###### Reconstruct JSON

You might want to break this down and debug

```py
cols = []
for company, lines in mapping.items():
    cols.append(F.struct(
        F.col(f'data.{company}.invoiceno'),
        F.col(f'data.{company}.name'),
        F.col(f'data.{company}.companyId'),
        F.col(f'data.{company}.departmentId'),
        F.array([f'data.{company}.lines.{line}' for line in lines]).alias('lines')
    ))

(df
    .select(
        F.col('success'),
        F.col('numRows'),
        F.array(cols).alias('data')
    )
    .printSchema()
)

root
 |-- success: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- numRows: long (nullable = true)
 |-- data: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- invoiceno: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- companyId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- departmentId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- lines: array (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- amount: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- invoiceline: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- productid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- quantity: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Hi, looks like a great plan to find a solution, but I get this error:

KeyError: 'No StructField named data'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-3593811266597553> in <module>
      3 df = spark.read.json(file)
      4 
----> 5 mapping = {d.name: d.dataType[3].dataType.fieldNames() for d in df.schema['data'].dataType.fields}

Comment: Hm, looks like you don't have `data` like your sample json ?